# Unbump a question if the answer providing the bump is deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, bump

I noticed that [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38025/how-do-i-activate-the-lanayru-desert-mining-co-stone-cache-power-generator) got bumped to the front page recently. By clicking the `?lastactivity` link I was taken to just the top of the question and saw no edits or answers since November, which probably means that whatever bumped it was deleted. The user that caused the bump has no rep or actions so I'm guessing it was a "not a real answer" deletion.

This seems a bit lame to me. At the end of the day, a question got bumped onto the front page for no real reason. It has no reason to take up space there; it's already been sufficiently answered and the only cause of the bump was an answer that (most likely) wasn't a real answer.

I think that if a question gets bumped because of a new answer, and that answer is deleted because it's not a real answer (or is spam or whatever), the question should get unbumped.

Comment: I dunno; if a question is *losing* an answer, one could argue that it could stand to have the extra, momentary attention of being bumped.

Comment: I'm talking about cases where the answer is lost because it was spam/not-an-answer; once it's deleted the question is basically unchanged.

Comment: There are *many* reasons the answer could have been deleted. My comment stands for all of them. It really isn't a big deal. Heck... the system *randomly* bumps old posts, too.

Answer (score 11):

This would cause a problem. Imagine this:

1. Spammer posts an answer linking to `real-rolex-watches-and-awesome-seo-services.info`.
2. Spammer immediately deletes the answer.
3. Spammer waits for an hour.
4. Spammer undeletes the answer.

The fact that this answer was posted would never cause the question to be on the front page, thus nobody may notice what's going on. After all, the bumping is also there to allow people to review what's changed. Granted, even with the way it currently works, only 10ks and mods would see the issue, but with your change, nobody would.

The only way to solve this then would be to cause an undeletion to bump a post. That however gives you a free, no-questions-asked, no-disadvantage way to continuously bump a post.

Comment: If deleting bumps the post and undeleting doesn't, then don't you already have this "a free, no-questions-asked, no-disadvantage way to continuously bump a post" anyway?

Comment: Deleting doesn't bump the post.

Comment: I don't know what the best answer is, but I can motivate solving the problem. For <10k users, it's pretty annoying when reading new activity from the front page that some of it might just be from bad new answers immediately deleted by mods. 10k users can at least see the deleted answers and quickly realize, but <10k users (assuming they even know that this can happen) have to scroll through and see that there's nothing new, or remember the username and search for it. Sometimes I spend as much time doing this as reading actual new content.

Comment: If you can imagine a problem, you can imagine a solution... If a spammer undeletes the answer, get it to be 'bumped' to frontpage. In the end, that was the last activity on that question.

Comment: [Link back](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1698/641) to Cooking.SE meta discussion.

Comment: @GUIJunkie No, that leads to the problem mentioned here (and I also mentioned it on cooking): users can undelete their posts in order to deliberately bump them. Potential solutions are messier; you have to distinguish between owner deletion and mod deletion.

Comment: @Jefromi. Ah, right. Understood. We people are awful, sometimes.

Comment: Isn't it trivial to find such posts now with review queues?