# Adding post notices bumps questions, but removing them doesn't

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bump, post-notices

I just saw this on the main page of MSO and clicked the "**10h ago**" link to see what change Adam made:

[image]

I was taken to the top of [the question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/) with no indication of what activity Adam performed. So I checked [the revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/116891/revisions) and saw this:

[image]

It seems a little odd to me that "notice added" generates a bump but "notice removed" doesn't. I guess this could be by design, but I thought it was worth posting here and finding out for sure.

Comment: Possibly related: [unbump a question if the answer providing the bump is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/unbump-a-question-if-the-answer-providing-the-bump-is-deleted)

Answer (score 3):

That notice must have been from a bounty, so the bumping act was starting a bounty on that question. Other notices (that only moderators can add) don't bump questions at all.

Bumping questions that get a bounty is likely intentional and one of the benefits of adding the bounty. Notices are a moderator-only privilege and don't bump at all, as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Once bumped questions are not un-bumped even if the action that bumped it is rolled back or reverted.

This allows people to review the rolled back state, which is as important as allowing people to review any other change to a post.

In this case I placed a bounty that a moderator removed.

Comment: So I just [discovered](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/837279#837279) after stopping by chat.

Comment: @PopularDemand Ha!  I'm glad someone screenshot that.