# Would it be feasible to implement a (tightly restricted) unbump?

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump, homepage

I just came across a question on the front page of Meta from 2008. This happens about once a month. Heck, it might happen more often but I only notice when the question is wildly obsolete. Often it asks about something that was implemented 3 years ago, in a vague "should we have this sort of thing?" way that is anachronistic now.

I worry that people will comment and answer on something that has been over for a long time. I worry that people will form an inaccurate opinion of the current state of the system. I'm mildly annoyed that I got sucked into reading something that is obsolete and not important. And why is this happening? Because someone fixed a spelling mistake or other tiny issue in a post that was otherwise long dead.

Now don't get me wrong. I'm not arguing for there to be any kind of non bumping edit. I've argued against non bumping edits before and will again. But after I've read it, and ascertained that all the answers are from 5 years ago and all that's happened is a minor spelling fix on one of them, could I please somehow **unbump the question**? So that it no longer is on the front page?

An `unbump` or `silence` link, after the post that was just changed, next to the edit/flag/share links, would be great. If necessary, require some number of them and show progress like with close: `unbump(1)` would work for me. Make it 10k or 20k, make it the "what should be offer people who get past 20k?" rep, heck make it diamond only and I'll flag to ask them to do it. But please, can we make the obsolete stuff sink back down to where it was?

Comment: A relevant close reason (something indicating that it's obsolete) would probably be enough; as that would indicate from the question list that discussion is closed on that issue.

Comment: Ah, well, I long for close as obsolete too. I'll take that as a consolation prize to be sure.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/unbump-a-question-if-the-answer-providing-the-bump-is-deleted

Comment: @random, no, this is an edit (probably not truly needed) on an answer that doesn't need to be deleted. Not a new pointless answer, but a pointless edit.

Comment: You can close as obsolete on meta sites, and on some regular sites

Comment: I don't think of the no-repro reason as obsolete, but you're right it does say "changes to circumstances have rendered it obsolete". Still, it's not a general solution.

Comment: I think "no-repro" applies to cases like this; the situation motivating the question is no longer present, so can't be "reproduced".  MSE has the "no-repro" close reason and all metas have a "no-repro" status tag (moderator only).  That doesn't help with typo-bumps, but we *do* have a way to signal that a question is no longer applicable, so for those cases we should use it.

Comment: Better approach in my opinion is to add "ignore" link which will simply remove the ignored question from the user's front page and ordinary question lists, as if the question is tagged with an ignored tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard would that affect everyone or just me? I can easily ignore it once I know what's going on. The issue is everyone else.

Comment: Just per user, like ignored tags. I don't agree doing it globally since some people would like to see those bumped questions.

Comment: I don't think there's anyone on the planet who needs to see that in one of 5 7-year old answers to a 7-year old question, `it's` has been corrected to `its` or `your` to 'you're` or the like. That would be what the link/button would be for. An experienced user looking over the change and deciding it really shouldn't be a bump. I would roll the edit back if I thought it would unbump but it doesn't.